# How to pass default data when creating a form holding a CollectionType?

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-forms

I am trying to create  multi import data, so I need many form collection this same class in one place. I can do this using collection type.

I created pictures Class with have one field: pictures and it is  arrayCollection type like this:

```
class Pictures {

protected $pictures;


public function __construct()
{
    $this->pictures = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

public function addPicture(Picture $picture)
{
    $this->pictures[] = $picture;
    return $this;
}

public function removePicture(Picture $picture)
{
    $this->pictures->removeElement($picture);
}

public function getPictures()
{
    return $this->pictures;
}
```

}

Next I created pictures form with collection to pictureType.

```
$builder
        ->add('pictures', 'collection', array(
            'prototype' => false,
            'by_reference' => true,
            'entry_type'   => PictureType::class,
            'options' => array('label' => false)) 
        )
    ;
```

Next I have picture Entity  with fields for example name, width, height, image (nevermind).

So my PictureType is a simple form fith fields that same like Entity (standard).

Now I try to render this form and add some picture in controller (not from database). Then I create Picture Object and next I add it to pictures->addPicture($picture);

```
$pictures = new Pictures();
    foreach($data as $d){            
        $picture = new Picture();            
        $picture->setName($d['title']);
        $picture->setImage($d['thumbnail_400_url']);
        $picture->setWidth($d['width']);
        $picture->setHeight($d['height']);
        $pictures->addPicture($picture);          
    }
    $form = $this->createForm('PicturesType', $pictures, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('dashboard_fotolia_save'),
            'method' => 'POST',
        ));
```

After it if rendered form is ok. I can see and change values.

But after submit form data disapear. I hope data will be stored in response but not:(

I want to use it only for create new object. Could you help me?

Form errors: This form should not contain extra fields

Answer (score 1):

Actually it seems that your `PicturesType` holds a `pictures` field since you add it with :

```
$builder->add('pictures', 'collection', ...
```

So you got a form type with holds an array of data with a key 'pictures' for the corresponding fields.

You may want to set it by :

```
$form = $this->createForm('PicturesType', array('pictures' => $pictures), ...
```